# Customize Google Maps +/- Buttons JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone know of a simple way to restyle the Google Maps JavaScript API mobile =/- buttons?

Here is a screenshot of what I am talking about:

[image: =/- buttons]

I am using the standard Google Maps v3 JavaScript API to load the maps.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could make your on elements with html and css and change the zoom level on click event.

Comment: @JoãoMosmann That is a good idea. Is there a way to hide the Zoom? (the reason I ask is because the zoom buttons appear different on desktop and mobile, so they may not share a common CSS class)

Comment: When creating a instance of google maps. You have to pass a option saying to hide the default UI.

``var mapOptions = {
    disableDefaultUI: true
   };
var mapInstance = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"),
mapOptions);``